# Fourier Transform of a symbolic expression

Tags: symbolic, fourier-analysis, design-patterns

Hello I would like to do the Fourier Transform of

```
H1'[t - L2[t]/c - L2primo[t]/c]
```

I know that its transform has to be:

```
i ω H1[ω]* Exp[- I ω (L2[t]/c + L2primo[t]/c)
```

I have considered L2[t] and L2primo[t] to be constant and not to be transformed...

In order to do that in mathematica I did this function:

```
Argomentof[e_] := Collect[e[[1, 2 ;;]], -1/c]
myFTd[f_, (q_: 1) expr_, ω_] := q*I* ω*f[ω]*Exp[I ω Argomentof[expr]];
```

if I do

```
myFTd[H1,L2primo[t]H1'[t - L2[t]/c - L2primo[t]/c] L2'[t])/c^2, ω]
```

I get:

```
(I Exp^(I ω L2primo[]) ω H1[ω])/c^2
```

that is wrong...anyone can help?

Comment: Why not use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform)? For example: ``FourierTransform[H1'[t-a],t,s,FourierParameters->{0,-1}]``

Comment: cause I have a symbolic signals, I did not have defined the value of H1, so it does not compute anything..in addition when I have terms which multiply my signal to be transform i don't know how to deal with it! indeed that is what i get from your suggestion :   I E^(-I a s) s FourierTransform[H1[t], t, s]..it did not compute H1[t]

Comment: But If I had another step like  I define myFT for a symbolic element:  myFT[f_[t_],\[Omega]_]:=f[\[Omega]] ,   and I do   FourierTransform[H1[t], t, \[Omega]] -> myFT[H1[t], \[Omega]]  I get this    I E^(-I a s) s H1[s]  ... thanks a lot for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform), and give an UpValue for `H1`. For example:

```
H1 /: FourierTransform[H1[t_], t_, s_] := OverHat[H1][s]
```

Then:

```
FourierTransform[H1'[t-a], t, s, FourierParameters->{0,-1}] //TeXForm
```

> $i s e^{-i a s} \hat{\operatorname{H1}}(s)$